# Why DNS look up is UDP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, network-protocols

1. UDP does not guarantee the message delivery
2. Does not guarantee ordered transmission.
3. Its connection less.

But per my understanding DNS should`be needing all these three features while lookup. Let's take the example when I enter`google.com` in browser

UDP will divide the google.com in small chunks/packets of data. Say these are goog and lee.com.

Questions on above points

1. if packet `goog` is lost in network for some reason, will browser not try to re transmit it and I will get error on browser ?
2. If `le.com` packet reaches prior to `goog`, receiver side will get the complete packet as `le.comgoog` . DNS server will not find any thing for the same ?
3. Browser creates the socket connection on source machine and sends the packets. Close the connection.
   Now get the response back from receiver side, as connection is closed . How OS will deliver the response received back to 
   browser application so that request can be sent to google server ? Does OS keeps the some information with itself so that once DNS response comes back
   it can look what was the initial request and sent it over to google server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UDP will divide the google.com in small chunks/packets of data

First – no, UDP itself does not fragment data. If the application sends the whole DNS query as a single datagram, the UDP layer does not divide it in any way; it remains a single datagram. Huge datagrams (above the size of IP MTU) may get fragmented by the **IP layer,** then transparently reassembled, and UDP still considers it a single datagram.

Second – the fragments aren't anywhere as small as that. They can be as large as the IP MTU allows. The original size limit of DNS query/response (before EDNS extension) was 512 bytes – this *always* fits in a single IP packet without any fragmentation.

(What does the DNS do if it needs to send a larger response than that? Well, it sends the first 512 bytes and sets the 'Truncated' flag in DNS response header. The client will then try the same query over TCP. Yes, DNS runs over TCP too.)

> if packet goog is lost in network for some reason, will browser not try to re transmit it and I will get error on browser ?

If individual IP fragments are lost, they will not be retransmitted – the whole packet is considered lost. UDP will not try to retransmit it.

(Note: the browser does not deal with individual IP fragments. If it sends a single UDP datagram that's too large to fit within the MTU, the necessary IP fragmentation is handled by the OS.)

However, the browser will usually retry by sending a whole *new DNS query* after a few seconds.

> If le.com packet reaches prior to goog, receiver side will get the complete packet as le.comgoog . DNS server will not find any thing for the same ?

This won't happen. IP fragments have the original offset written on them; even if they arrive out-of-order, they will be reassembled correctly anyway.

> Browser creates the socket connection on source machine and sends the packets. Close the connection. Now get the response back from receiver side, as connection is closed . How OS will deliver the response received back to browser application

The browser *doesn't* close the socket if it's still waiting for a DNS response.

> Does OS keeps the some information with itself so that once DNS response comes back it can look what was the initial request and sent it over to google server ?

That's all done by the browser itself. The browser performs DNS lookup before actually trying to contact the website itself, so it remembers the pending HTTP requests.

Comment: You said `This won't happen. IP fragments have the original offset written on them; even if they arrive out-of-order, they will be reassembled correctly anyway` Then it means UDP also guarantees order delivery. Then why it is said UDP does not guarantee order ? Second question on what you said ` The browser doesn't close the socket if it's still waiting for a DNS response.`

Comment: No, that's not an UDP guarantee. You're confusing UDP and IP. When an application sends two separate UDP datagrams, they are independent and can arrive in any order. However, the underlying _network_ might transfer those datagrams in smaller pieces (IP fragments), which it can do regardless of the transport layer (IP can fragment its payload whether it's UDP or TCP or GRE or SCTP) and invisibly to the transport layer (UDP still thinks it's dealing with exactly the same datagrams as before).

Comment: I think what you saying is that its the IP layer/protocol which transfer those datagrams in smaller pieces and rearrange the packets in order  if they are out of order.  Actual after reading one more time OSI model looks like TCP ensures the in order delivery while IP ensures to rearrange the packet to make it inorder in case of out of order. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think that sounds right... IP (the network layer) can transfer a single UDP datagram in several smaller pieces, if the network requires so. It only ensures order for those fragments that it itself created – but it doesn't ensure order between whole datagrams. The transport layer (e.g. TCP or SCTP) needs to do that job. (By the way, TCP tries to carefully choose its MSS so that IP will never need to perform additional fragmentation.)